# Need to retrieve hashed password without usage of LoginProperty

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to retrieve the hashed password on a linked server, since its a linked server I cant seem to just use LoginProperty in the query.  At the moment I go after the `sys.syslogins` but the password is stored in there as what appears to be Chinese lettering and what I need is something that is the varbinary form like:

```
0x0200DF5602211E3AEC954FDD54A114C59B6B07C72BAB3E6DFC7A2CE0046B0B7A6037EB9F5AE6E04005FF
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?  If I am missing a way to just use LoginProperty when going after a linked server that is fine as well.

If possible I would like to stick with querying the syslogins and convert what is stored there into something usable.

Answer (score 1):

Just run a passthrough query on the linked server.  EG

```
select * from openquery(LinkedServer,'select loginproperty(''SomeLogin'',''PasswordHash'') hash')
```